# ANSI JOIN ORACLE with 2 common tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, ansi-sql

I want to do that on oracle with ANSI JOIN:

```
SELECT *
   FROM TICKET,
        --here I have more tables that relates with TICKET
        TICKET_EVO,
        USER USR_CLIENT,
        USER USR_SUPPORT
 WHERE TICKET.ID = TICKET_EVO.ID --TICKET_EVO is child of TICKET
   AND TICKET.CD_USER = USR_CLIENT.CD_USER --TICKET has the client user that opened the ticket
   AND TICKET_EVO.CD_USER = USR_SUPPORT.CD_USER --TICKET_EVO has the support user that answer the client on each evolution
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM TICKET 
JOIN TICKET_EVO 
  ON TICKET.ID = TICKET_EVO.ID
JOIN USER USR_CLIENT
  ON TICKET.CD_USER = USR_CLIENT.CD_USER
JOIN USER USR_SUPPORT
  on TICKET_EVO.CD_USER = USR_SUPPORT.CD_USER
```

Comment: Solved! I didn't realize that I can put a alias like on the traditional SQL. Thanks a lot.